# Android Studio 4.1 is incompatible with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

It seems we can use [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup) in Android Studio 4.1 only. So I tried to update my IDE. But I got warning like the new build is incompatible with Kotlin,

**Screenshot**

[image]

Is that true? After then update can I use mentioned plugins or not?

Comment: @Gunasselan Please clarify one this that this is Android Preview 41. Canary.?

Comment: @yash786 Yes, This is Android Studio 4.1 Canary 4 build.

Comment: @Gunasselan Yes No need to worry you can go with the update For reference check:- https://github.com/yash786agg/JetPack-Compose#step-02-apps-buildgradle

Comment: @yash786 Thank you. I will proceed...